# There exists no matrix which does this operation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want a matrix A which takes

M=$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$

To

N=$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$

Such that

MA=N

I want explicit representation of A.

I think it is not possible. If it is not possible then why ?

Comment: $A$ must be a $2\times2$ matrix. Such a search can be done by explicitly putting $A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix} a&b\\ c&d\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and equating the two members. Otherwise there is that property of the determinant among $n\times n$ matrices: $\det(UV)=\det(U)\,\det(V)$, that could help.

Comment: You can also use $\mathrm{rank}(MA)\leq\min(\mathrm{rank}(M),\mathrm{rank}(A))\leq\mathrm{rank}(M)=1$ and $\mathrm{rank}(N)=2$. This contradicts $MA=N.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\ c&d\end{pmatrix}$

You want:
$$MA=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\ \:0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

That is:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\ c&d\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a+c&b+d\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Compare the R.H.S of the last 2 equations before, and since:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\ \:\:0&1\end{pmatrix}\:can't\:equal\:\begin{pmatrix}a+c&b+d\\ \:0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

We conclude that matrix $A$ does not exist.

You could also argue that $A$ does not exists since $M$ has no inverse (singular). This leads to a system of equations with no solution.

Answer (score 2):

No such $A$ exists. The equation $MA=N$ gives $$\det(MA)=\det(N)$$ $$\det(M)\det(A)=\det(N)$$ $$0 \times \det(A)=1$$ $$0=1$$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

$N$ has an inverse, and $M$ doesn't (since the detereminant of $N$ is non-zero, while the determinant of $M$ is zero).

But if $MA=N$, then $MAN^{-1}=NN^{-1}=I$, so $AN^{-1}$ is the inverse of $M$. Contradiction.